# Extension method to validate nullity when nullable reference are enabled

Tags: c#, exception, nullable-reference-types

I have the following method:

```
public static void NotNull<TException>([ValidatedNotNull] object? data, string? message = null) where TException : Exception, new()
```

Basically, I use it to ensure that `data` is not null. It works well, however, when I enable nullable reference, Visual Studio continues to underline in green the object I pass to this method because it considers that I didn't check whether it's null or not although I use the `ValidatedNotNull` attribute.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio that I validated the nullity of the object using my custom method?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the null forgiving operator? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving

Comment: I am but I don't think it should be usable in this case. If you use a method to validate nullity, you shouldn't have to use the null forgiving operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`NotNullAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullattribute?view=net-6.0) (see the [attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) docs):

> A nullable parameter, field, property, or return value will never be null.

```cs
static void NotNull<TException>([NotNull]object? data, string? message = null) where TException : Exception, new()
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: A small addition to the answer. If one wish to create a library that uses NotNull, he has to target netstandard2.1 as it is not present in netstandard2.0. Cheers